# MSMQ Messages Never Get Delivered - Sit in outbound when paused

Tags: c#, message-queue, msmq

I have 3 machines, let's call them A, B (both servers) and Dev (my local machine).

I want to send a message queue item from A to B.

The actual C# code I have is rather simple and honestly, I really do not think it is problem here. (It's a webapi that takes a POSTed object and just shoves it down the queue).

I can send these messages just fine from Dev to B (while logged into a domain admin account) without a problem and I can inspect the body of the messages. However I cannot send messages from A to B. The private queue on B is set to allow "Everyone" the "Full Control" permissions.

If I pause the outbound queue on A and send the messages, they sit in the outbound queue and the body is exactly as I would expect it to be, but when I resume that outbound queue again, they are never received on the other end at B.

I can't figure out what's going on for the life of me. I tried the 'TCP' method but I need to refer to my queues by machine name not IP.

For reference, the code used to send the message is:

```
using (var queue = new MessageQueue($"FormatName:Direct=OS:MachineB\\private$\\Queue"))
            {
                var queueItem = new QueueItem();
                queueItem.Object = this.postedObject;

                var message = new System.Messaging.Message(queueItem);
                queue.Send(message);
            }
```

Comment: Are both A and B on the same domain? Also, is the queue on B a transactional or non-transactional queue?

Comment: @tomredfern They are both on the same domain (along with Dev) and they are non-transactional :)

Comment: Turn on E2E tracing for MSMQ on both servers. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730882(v=ws.11).aspx. This should tell you exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference and anyone else who comes across this:

The project sending the messages to the queue was a webapi. It was running under the AppPoolIdentity account in IIS and despite the receiving queue allowing Everyone access, it was denying these messages, but gracefully. So the webapi would fire the message and wouldn't throw any exceptions, it'd hit the outbound, but then never arrive.

We switched the account to NetworkService and it worked just fine.